# Recursion from inside IIFE

Tags: javascript, recursion, iife

I have a piece of code which generates all the possible strings that can be made by placing spaces in-between the letters of a given string, the code uses recursion to achieve this. Here is the code I have (it's a [C++ source](https://ideone.com/4YaTSD) I have adapted to JavaScript and it works as expected):

```
    var genStringsUtil = function (str,buf,i,j,n){
      if(n == i){
        buf[j] = " ";
        console.log(buf.join(""));
        return;
      }
        buf[j] = str[i];
        genStringsUtil (str,buf,i+1,j+1,n);
        buf[j] = " ";
        buf[j+1] = str[i];
        genStringsUtil (str,buf,i+1,j+2,n);
    }

   var genStrings = function(s){
      var str = s;
      var n =str.length;
      var buf = [];
      buf[0] = str[0];

      genStringsUtil (str,buf,1,1,n);
    };

   function main(){
    genStrings("ABCDE");
   }

   main();
```

Now, I have modified it like this and it still works:

```
var genStrings = function (str,buf,i,j,n){
  if(n == i){
    buf[j] = " ";
    console.log(buf.join(""));
    return;
  }
  buf[j] = str[i];
  genStrings (str,buf,i+1,j+1,n);
  buf[j] = " ";
  buf[j+1] = str[i];
  genStrings (str,buf,i+1,j+2,n);
}

!function(s){
  var str = s;
  var n =str.length;
  var buf = [];
  buf[0] = str[0];

  genStrings (str,buf,1,1,n);
}("ABCDE");
```

However, when I change the last part to (IIFE with parentheses):

```
(function(s){
  var str = s;
  var n =str.length;
  var buf = [];
  buf[0] = str[0];

  genStrings (str,buf,1,1,n);
})("ABCDE");
```

I get an error :

> TypeError: j is undefined

If I put the closing parenthesis after ("ABCDE") like so:

```
(function(s){
  var str = s;
  var n =str.length;
  var buf = [];
  buf[0] = str[0];

  genStrings (str,buf,1,1,n);
}("ABCDE"));
```

I get another error :

> TypeError: genStrings is not a function

I always thought that IIFEs declared with ! or the parentheses were the same thing, but obviously not. So my question is basically what is going on that is different in those three cases? Is recursion the issue?

I hope my message is not too long.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You forgot a semicolon, so `genStrings` is being invoked immediately because of your parentheses. VTC'ing as typo. Consider using a linter

Comment: Thank you. I don't see where I'm missing a semi-colon? I get two different error messages depending on where the closing parenthesis is. If it's before the argument **("ABCDE")**, I get  _j is undefined_ even if I add a semi-colon before **("ABCDE")**. For the second case I don't see where I'm missing the semicolon.

Comment: You need a semicolon after the whole `genStrings` function, else it will be invoked immediately because the `function() { }` is immediately followed by `(...)` (interpreted as a call)

Comment: Sorry I just realized what you meant as I validated my answer. It works now. Thank you for your help. One last question, what do you mean by _VTC'ing as typo_

Comment: VTC = voting to close. (Typo questions are off-topic for SO and should be closed)

Answer (score 0):

C++ has several limitations that JavaScript does not have. There are countless ways to encode your function in JavaScript, but here is one that uses [continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style).

In this style, a second parameter `send` is added to your `genStrings` function's signature and accepts the default `identity` continuation. This effectively turns `return` into a user-configurable function. The name `send` is used because `return` is a reserved keyword.

Another notable aspect of this implementation is the use of [referential transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency), a property of functional style, where a function always returns the same result for the same inputs. As recursion is a functional heritage, we are sure to maintain this property to yield the best result.

```js
const identity = x =>
  x
  
const concat = (xs, ys) =>
  xs .concat (ys)
  
const genStrings = ([ char, ...rest ], send = identity) =>
  // base case: return empty set
  char === undefined
    ? send ([])

  // if there is only one char, return singleton result
  : rest.length === 0
    ? send ([char])
  
  // otherwise recur on rest
  // 1) add char plus space to each combination
  // 2) add char without space to each combination
  // 3) concat the result
  : genStrings
      ( rest
      , combs =>
          send ( concat ( combs .map (c => char + ' ' + c)
                        , combs .map (c => char + c)
                        )
               )
      )

console.log (genStrings ('ABC'))
// [ 'A B C'
// , 'A BC'
// , 'AB C'
// , 'ABC'
// ]
```

You'll also notice that there's no need for keeping track of several other state variables like `n`, `i`, and `j`, nor the need to increment them with different values. Programs using fewer expressions and variables are easier to maintain and easier to debug.

`genStrings` works with larger inputs too, like the example in your question

```
console.log (genStrings ('ABCDE'))
// [ 'A B C D E'
// , 'A B C DE'
// , 'A B CD E'
// , 'A B CDE'
// , 'A BC D E'
// , 'A BC DE'
// , 'A BCD E'
// , 'A BCDE'
// , 'AB C D E'
// , 'AB C DE'
// , 'AB CD E'
// , 'AB CDE'
// , 'ABC D E'
// , 'ABC DE'
// , 'ABCD E'
// , 'ABCDE'
// ]
```

We were also careful to make `genStrings` a [total program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_functional_programming), meaning it returns a valid result, even when the input string is empty

```
console.log (genStrings (''))
// []
```

Because `genStrings` is defined using continuation-passing style, we can specify a user-configurable continuation at the call site as well

```
genStrings ('ABC', console.log)
// [ 'A B C', 'A BC', 'AB C', 'ABC' ]

genStrings ('ABC', combs => combs.length)
// 4

genStrings ('ABC', combs => combs .join (', '))
// 'A B C, A BC, AB C, ABC'
```

As `genStrings` is a pure function with a well-defined domain (input) and codomain (output), there's no need for an immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE), let alone the need to debug one.

---

> I started studying it but I cannot understand what is the : colon syntax before rest.length === 0 and genStrings?

`?:` is JavaScript's [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), also called the *ternary operator*. The syntax is `conditionExpression ? trueExpression : falseExpression`. When `conditionExpression` evaluates to a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value, only `trueExpression` is evaluated, and `falseExpression` is skipped. Contrarily, if `conditionExpression` evaluates to a non-truthy value, the `trueExpression` is skipped and only the `falseExpression` is evaluated.

It is the expressional equivalent of the `if`-`else` statement, but instead of relying upon side-effects, it evaluates to a value, as do all other expressions.

```
// conditional expression
let someValue =
  n === 0                // expression
    ? "n is zero"        // expression
    : "n is not zero"    // expression

// if statement
let someValue
if (n === 0)
  someValue = "n is zero"         // side effect
else
  someValue = "n is not zero"     // side effect
```

Above, the `if` statement is more verbose and relies upon side effects to set the value for `someValue`. The conditional expression evaluates to a value and can be directly assigned to a variable.

Similar to `if`-`else if`-`else` statements, conditional expressions can also be chained together. This is the syntax you're seeing in the answer above.

```
const animalSound =
  animal === "dog"    // if
    ? "woof"          // then

  : animal === "cat"  // else if
    ? "meow"          // then

  : "unknown"         // else
```

It helps me to see the same program represented in a variety of ways. Below, we rewrite the original answer using imperative-style `if` statements

```js
const identity = x =>
  x

const concat = (xs, ys) =>
  xs .concat (ys)

const genStrings = ([ char, ...rest ], send = identity) =>
{ if (char === undefined)
    return send ([])

  else if (rest.length === 0)
    return send ([char])

  else
    return genStrings
             ( rest
             , combs =>
                 send ( concat ( combs .map (c => char + ' ' + c)
                               , combs .map (c => char + c)
                               )
                      )
             )
}

console.log (genStrings ('ABC'))
// [ 'A B C'
// , 'A BC'
// , 'AB C'
// , 'ABC'
// ]
```

Comment: thank you for the response. I started studying it but I cannot understand what is the : colon syntax before _rest.length === 0_ and _genStrings_?

Comment: you're welcome. I made an update to the answer to reply to your comment.

Comment: thank you! I knew about the ternary operator but I didn't know you could do _else if_-like structures by chaining them. Great :)